# mysql ajax search query

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

hello friends i am making a live search with the help of ajax and mysql. the problem is that when we write something suppose a alphabet "a" then it gives live results but when i put a space and then write any alphabet suppose "a" then results does no shows up . how can we ignore the spaces in the search ?? my code is

**ajax search.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".search").keyup(function() 
 {
  var searchbox = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'searchword='+ $.trim(searchbox);

  if(searchbox=='')
 {
 $('#display123').hide();
 }

 else
{

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
  url: "friends/search1.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html)
  {
  $("#display123").html(html).show();
  }
   });
  }return false;    


  });
  });
   </script>
```

**mysql search1.php**

```
         <?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sexy/include/connection.php");
     if($_POST)
     {
      $q=$_POST['searchword'];
     $sql_res=mysql_query("select * from users_profile where fname like '%$q%'  or     Email like '%$q%' order by rand() LIMIT 10");
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
  {
      $fname=$row['fname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $img=$row['profile_pic'];
    $country=$row['country'];
       $uid=$row['uid'];

          $re_fname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
   $re_lname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';

    $final_fname = str_ireplace($q, $re_fname, $fname);

      $final_lname = str_ireplace($q, $re_lname, $lname);


     ?>

           <div class="display_box" >
      <span><a href="profile.php?f_id=<?php echo $uid;?>"><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>"                width="50" height="50" style="float:left; margin-right:6px" /></a></span>
    <div class="searchtext"><a href="profile.php?f_id=<?php echo $uid;?>"><?php echo             $final_fname; ?>&nbsp;<br/>
    <span style="font-size:10px; color:#999999"><?php echo $country; ?></span></a></div></div>
    <?php
     }
      }
  else
    {
    }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trim whitespaces before using the variable in query, like:

```
$q= trim($_POST['searchword']); //remove whitespaces from front and end
```

Comment: hello thanks for answer but when i use this and put space in search box then it shows fetch all the records of every alphabet, even before entering any alphabet yet.

Comment: What we've done implementing a live search is to not run the search if the `LEN()` of the search box is 1 (or 2) characters.  Most of the time, those searches are not useful anyway.